# log4net use local server time ,need to change to utc time

Tags: asp.net, log4net-configuration

I'm using log4net to write logs in asp .net application,log time are written in local server time but I need in utc format and is  there any time zone specific tags already available in log4net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log4Net: Log with UTC times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012083/log4net-log-with-utc-times)

Answer (score 1):

The Parameter your log4net value you are looking for is `%utcdate`
For example when you add a database parameter to your configfile:

```
 <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@utcdate" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403936/log4Net-and-SQLite